# vertical-align with line-heights does not work as it should

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

So I have div with such style options:

```
div.Holder {
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
text-align: center;
border-top: 3px #E7E7E7 solid;
color: #535353;
}
```

Inside that div there is span with such options:

```
.Holder > span { display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 15px;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

So the text inserted into

`<div class="Holder"><span> here </span></div>`

should be centered vertically and horizontally and it is in document with

*`'<!DOCTYPE html>`'*,

but when I had inserted such elements to

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

page the text just goes to the top of the div.

Unless I remove line-height property from span element, but then if there is more than one line of text - second line is not visible, because text uses `line-height: 45px.`

How should I deal this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work try something like this

```
div.Holder {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.Holder > span {
    display: table;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

example:
**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5vv9N/2/)**

and always use the css reset

Comment: With your example text goes under div space: http://imageshack.com/a/img541/2217/2x1d.png because, of 15px padding... I gues I will use position: absolute with top: 50%, and margin-top: -half height of span, which will be defined using javascript...

Comment: if you want to use js to this it would be nice and safer :)